# Checkbox always return true in gridview(parent) inside gridview(child) using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, gridview

I have used checkbox in inside `gridview`
I don't use all code here, checkbox always return true in child `gridview`, I display parent-child records using + button (clicking on + parent `gridview` then display child records in child `gridview`)

```
GridView Parent
Start
    Gridview Child
    Start
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Schema">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CHKA"  checked= '<%# Eval("Add") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

    End
End
```

I clicked on the save button, the `checkbox` always returns the true value.
On Save Button

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvParent.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  GridView gvChild = (GridView)gvParent.Rows[i].FindControl("gvChild");

  for (int j = 0; j < gvChild.Rows.Count; j++)
      {
           CheckBox CHKA = (CheckBox)gvChild.Rows[j].FindControl("CHKA");
      }
 }
```

Comment: have you handled `Page.IsPostBack` while filling data in gridview?

Comment: Yes, I have handled filled the parent grid view data,
when the parent row expand then I will fill the chid records on rowdatabound event.

Comment: the issue has resolved . I have removed the panel before the inner gridview.